# ActionBarSherlock doesn't show title

Tags: android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar, android-fragmentactivity, android-support-library

```
public class Intro extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.generic);

        final ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
        bar.setTitle("test title");
        bar.setTitle("test subtitle");
```

The last two lines have no effect: the title and the subtitle are simply not set. The action bar only contains the logo. Strangely, I haven't found any similar questions, so I must be doing something very wrong.

This is the layout file `generic.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to put `bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);` before setting title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an hour of frustration I noticed that for some reason I had the following call a few lines down the road:

```
bar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
```

Never code after midnight...